# KDE installation

Tags: apt, kubuntu, themes, kde, fonts

Hi everyone i installed KDE and nothing changed so I tried
    sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop

which told me this

```
plasma-desktop is already the newest version (4:5.6.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-roboto fonts-roboto-hinted gdebi-core gnome-icon-theme
  libcec-platform1v5 libcec3 libfstrcmp0 libhdhomerun2 libjs-iscroll
  libmicrohttpd10 libnfs8 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 python-imaging python-pil
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I did reboot and everything but nothing changed. The theme is still the same.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: How did you install KDE?

Comment: i did the following

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports `
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: First, log out. Then on the Ubuntu login screen, try clicking on the Ubuntu logo near your username. There should be a list of installed desktop environments to choose from.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I'll post my comment as an answer

Comment: As you are a relatively new user, if the below answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved by ticking the gray mark next to the number of votes. This way, future users will know that there is a working answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like KDE installed successfully, but the login manager is still defaulting to Unity. To load KDE, you'll need to manually select it in the login screen.

First, log out. Then on the Ubuntu login screen, try clicking on the Ubuntu logo near your username. There should now be a list of installed desktop environments to choose from. Choose "KDE", log in as you usually do (i.e. type your password if requested to) and you're good to go!